# Issue With Getting the Correct Data (doubles and ints)- C++

Tags: c++, int, double, static-cast

So the issue that I'm running into with this piece of code is that if the repetitions exceed 6 then the program crashes. Playing around with it I realized first of all the sums weren't showing up correctly with some couts I placed to test, changing everything to int makes it so the program doesn't crash, but doesn't show the decimals like I need. I am using static cast correctly I thought, but it doesn't seem to add up. I even tried leaving the sum variables as int and keep the average times as a double, but that didn't work either.

I can't figure out for the life of me why it would only work up to 6 repetitions and then crash after that. Here is the piece of code that is causing the issue:

```
void displayResults(int timingArray1[], int timingArray2[], char sortType1[], char sortType2[], int numRepetitions) {
    double sum1 = 0;
    double sum2 = 0;
    double averageTime1, averageTime2;
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < numRepetitions; index++) {
        sum1 = sum1 + timingArray1[index];
        sum2 = sum2 + timingArray2[index];
    }
    averageTime1 = (sum1) / static_cast<double>(numRepetitions);
    averageTime2 = (sum2) / static_cast<double>(numRepetitions);
    cout << "SORTING RESULTS" << endl;
    cout << "---------------" << endl;
    cout << setw(15) << sortType1 << " Sort     " << fixed << setprecision(1) << averageTime1 << " clock ticks on average" << endl;
    cout << setw(15) << sortType2 << " Sort     " << fixed << setprecision(1) << averageTime2 << " clock ticks on average" << endl;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell (from the call stack) where it is crashing? The code seems fine to me, so my guess is that your `timingArray` don't actually have all the observations that you think they have, and when you try to reference an element beyond the limit.

Comment: Yea, I checked the timingArray and it appears that everything is there that should be. I shall check again and update!

Comment: Oh, and it is crashing right after the sortType1 and "Sort" are printed. From the couts there is no valid averageTime to display though.

Comment: 'I am using static_cast correctly I thought'. Actually static_cast is unnecessary in this situation. When you divide a double by an int, the int is converted to a double automatically. Other than that I agree with the other commentator, the error is in the code you haven't posted.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback both of you!

Comment: Why not use `std::string` instead of character arrays?  The issue could be that `sortType2` is bogus, thus causing the crash.

Comment: Cannot duplicate when given valid input: http://ideone.com/RDjGAu  Please post the driver program that calls this function and duplicates the error.

Comment: Don't count on screen output to tell you where a crash is. More could have been written into cout and didn't make it onto the display before the program crashed.

Comment: Problem fixed! Was an issue with the timingArray in main. Thank you for all your help everyone.